# Saving model on backbone localstorage

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I am using jeromegn localstorage plugin https://github.com/jeromegn/backbone.localStorage.

```
model.set(data);
model.save();
console.log(model)  // I am getting the json 
console.log(JSON.stringify(localStorage['Session']));  // I am getting the model's Id
```

I am trying to save a model it seems though to save only my model's Id ?

Comment: Does your model have an ID? I don't know if it's changed in a more recent release or not but in the past I needed to add `defaults: { id: 1 }` when trying to save a model on its own (that is not through a collection).

Comment: It does have an Id, I have added the defaults: {id: 1} and didn't work.

Comment: I am tracing localstorage and been able to see that there are to records.
localStorage['Session'] // The model's id
localStorage['Session-"model's id"'] // The saved model 

Is that the default behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you forgot to add model to collection

```
this.mycollection.add(model)
```

Have u write localStorage: new Store("backbone-todo") in backbone collection
for eg.

```
var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: urModel,
localStorage: new Store('Session')
});
```

crate instance of collection like this

```
var mycollection = new collection();
```

and then
    model.set(data);
    model.save();
    this.mycollection.add(model)